# PIC16F153 UART Echo some byte duplication

Tags: c, uart

I use communication via UART on PIC16. I transfer data, **but SOME BYTES are DUPLICATED**.

I will be grateful for any idea, that might solve problem.

[image]

I generated UART functions via MCC in MPLAB.

The oscillator is external and set to 18.432MHz for baud rate 115200 giving zero error.

```c
//Simple code sample:

void main(void)
{
    uint8_t data;
    
    SYSTEM_Initialize();

    // When using interrupts, you need to set the Global and Peripheral Interrupt Enable bits
    // Use the following macros to:

    // Enable the Global Interrupts
    INTERRUPT_GlobalInterruptEnable();

    // Enable the Peripheral Interrupts
    INTERRUPT_PeripheralInterruptEnable();
    
    while (1)
    {
        if (EUSART2_is_rx_ready())
        {
            data = EUSART2_Read();    
            EUSART2_Write(data);         
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if the data is coming so fast that you're trying to `EUSART2_Write` before the previous byte fully clocked out.  Perhaps the test should be `if (EUSART2_is_rx_ready() && EUSART2_is_tx_done())` might help?  (this feels like a longshot)

Comment: What are your communication parameters beside the baud rate? Please [edit] your question and add them for PC and PIC. For example, do you use different numbers of stop bits?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but looking at the (presumably) the source [here](https://vcs.designtrail.net/dslc/rn4870-ble-test/raw/7db54074058f646814cf9de14fa6e3cda01d8029/mcc_generated_files/eusart2.c), `EUSART2_Read` is blocking, so there is no need to check `EUSART2_is_rx_ready` before.

Comment: @SteveFriedl Not so far-fetched at all. 115200 = 7.68us/bit. 10 bits = 86.8us. Meaning that the total overhead code from the point that a byte arrives in UART rx register until another byte is placed in UART tx register, must be executed in less than 86.8us or data will get corrupted. Not a tough real-time requirement for a modern MCU, but probably a very tough requirement for some completely outdated 8-bitter like a PIC. Especially if it relies on some bloatware libs.

Comment: I have some vague memory that PIC system clock prescales from the oscillator by 4. If so the system clock is 4.6MHz = 217ns per tick. Meaning there's 400 ticks available in 86.8us. Some 3-4 tick per instruction gives 100 instructions. And then consider function call head etc.

Comment: On a completely different note, why does the screenshot say DTR and RTS are active? Is  hardware handshaking used?

Comment: It appears that this program is doing nothing more than echoing its input: how certain are we that the *input data* isn't doubled?

Comment: @Lundin, Steve Friedl, look at the code I linked above. These routines are interrupt-driven and blocking. `Write` is not supposed to transmit anything before the previous data was sent.

Comment: I believe there is some comm parameters mismatch, as @thebusybee suggests

Comment: @EugeneSh. I wonder how well-tested that code is. Because it looks like it has race condition bugs to me. What's protecting the ISR from interrupting the EUSART2_Read() function when it tries to access the buffer? And similarly during writes.

Comment: Quick & dirty check to see if race condition bugs could be the culprit: `if (EUSART2_is_rx_ready()) { INTERRUPT_GlobalInterruptDisable(); data = EUSART2_Read(); EUSART2_Write(data); INTERRUPT_GlobalInterruptEnable(); }`. If you are unlucky, this could magically solve everything.

Comment: I will try to clarify my question

- settings 115200,data=8bit,parity=none,stopbit=1 both devices have the same PC and PIC.
- DTR and RTS signals are not used

data is only duplicated between the EUSART_read() and EUSART_write() functions
tested by external TX wiretapping


disable and enable interrupt in loop - didn't help reversing is the same

I'll try to go into more detail about the code from MCC because I was counting on it being straight from the microchip
Thanks